# Unable to track eyes using tracking.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, tracking.js

I am creating a eye staring game. I have used meteorjs, trackingjs for tracking stuffs and peerjs for streaming. In the older version of trackingjs , eye detecting feature was already there but in the new version only the face detecting feature is available.
Here is the demo app which only tracks the face. 
http://sushantbaj.meteor.com/
and this is my link to my github repo:
https://github.com/sushant12/eye-staring
In the docs of trackingjs, it is said that

> In order to use object tracker, you need to instantiate the
>   constructor passing the classifier data to detect:

```
var objects = new tracking.ObjectTracker(['face', 'eye', 'mouth']);
```

So I passed 'eye' as a parameter but it did not track my eye.

```
    var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker('eye');
tracker.setInitialScale(4);
tracker.setStepSize(2);
tracker.setEdgesDensity(0.1);

      tracking.track('#video', tracker, { camera: true });

      tracker.on('track', function(event) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
          context.strokeStyle = '#a64ceb';
          context.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
          context.font = '11px Helvetica';
          context.fillStyle = "#fff";
          context.fillText('x: ' + rect.x + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 11);
          context.fillText('y: ' + rect.y + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 22);
        });
      });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @boszlo question is updated.

Comment: @RajShakya I don't agree with the downvote and am interested in this stuff, but your question still... doesn't contain a question?

Comment: @somethinghere question again updated

Comment: the meteor link appears to be broken..

Comment: @Aneeshmg i removed the repo while cleaning my github. I work only with ruby now. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

```
var tracker = new tracking.ObjectTracker('eye');
tracker.setStepSize(1.7);

tracking.track('#video', tracker, { camera: true });

tracker.on('track', function(event) {
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

event.data.forEach(function(rect) {
  context.strokeStyle = '#a64ceb';
  context.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);

});
});
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I'm curious - following along with this code just makes the rectangle to highlight the eyes shoved off to the side. Am i missing something here?